# different class label for different test data files (GRT)

Tags: c++, gesture-recognition, training-data

I have grt labelled classification data file for different gestures in different files. How do I create a GRT::ClassificationData object with different class labels for each of the input files?
Here are first few lines of the two different training data files for 2 different gestures:

```
GRT_LABELLED_CLASSIFICATION_DATA_FILE_V1.0
DatasetName: NOT_SET
InfoText: 
NumDimensions: 3
TotalNumTrainingExamples: 654
NumberOfClasses: 1
ClassIDsAndCounters: 
1   654 NOT_SET
UseExternalRanges: 0
LabelledTrainingData:
1   0.00681441  0.00192668  -0.999975
1   0.212607    -0.0418175  0.976243
1   0.105986    -0.0631664  0.992359
```

and

```
GRT_LABELLED_CLASSIFICATION_DATA_FILE_V1.0
DatasetName: NOT_SET
InfoText: 
NumDimensions: 3
TotalNumTrainingExamples: 1336
NumberOfClasses: 1
ClassIDsAndCounters: 
1   1336    NOT_SET
UseExternalRanges: 0
LabelledTrainingData:
1   -0.0139121  0.00375727  -0.999896
1   0.728981    0.675366    -0.111654
1   0.751433    0.629043    -0.199132
```

I am completely new to GRT library, please give a little detailed answer(probably with an example?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

1.Load each file in different ClassificationData instances

```
 //Load training data from different files
    ClassificationData trainingData1;
    ClassificationData trainingData2;
    ClassificationData trainingData3;
    trainingData1.loadDatasetFromFile("file1");
    trainingData2.loadDatasetFromFile("file2");
    trainingData3.loadDatasetFromFile("file3");
```

2.Relabel instances to different classlabels

```
    //relabelling data before merging them
    //optional step, depending on the data
    trainingData2.relabelAllSamplesWithClassLabel(1,3);
    trainingData3.relabelAllSamplesWithClassLabel(1,4);
```

3.Combine all ClassificationData instances

```
    //Merging all data
    trainingData1.merge(trainingData2);
    trainingData1.merge(trainingData3);
```

Now there is a single file with all records combined. For not going through these steps repeatedly, do this once and use saveDatasetToFile().